# Access to Security Portal (Scanner) when building 2GP

Tags: security-review, partner-portal, security-scanner

I work as a PDO partner for a customer who wants to have an app on App Exchange. We develop a 2GP package, where Dev Hub is located in the customer PBO, which is linked as an organization to App Exchange/Partner Community account.
We have access to their Partner Community account, where we help them manage the listing, but now we want to run the Security Scanner using their account.
Unfortunately, neither my user from Partner Community nor my colleague with a Developer license user in the PBO can access the scanner: [image: image with problem]

So, the question is: **what kind of user (environment, license type, permissions) do I need to be able to access the security portal** (https://security.secure.force.com/sourcescanner)?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this and I hit the same error message; which is a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

The documentation is https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/security_review_partner_security_portal_scanners.htm; but that doesn't speak to the issue that you are facing. 

At a glance, it would suggest that you don't have a valid Partner login or don't have the Author Apex permission but that seems unlikely based on what you've said. 

Is Salesforce Support able to help?

Comment: @andy-hitchings Actually, you may have hit the spot, because the Developer License does not give you the Author Apex option (is not needed, as code is stored in the repository and we just need access to scratch orgs and namespace). I've missed the Author Apex part on the page, I will run more tests with this access and see if it helps, thanks!